# How many hibernate mapping files required?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have four tables in four different databases . I want to use these four tables in one program . In this scenario how many Hibernate  mapping files to configure this application ?

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you mean by 4 different databases.is it 4 different schemas in same db or is it 4 different db on sane server.

Comment: Yes, 4 different db on sane server

Comment: Ideally, you should be using annotation configuration instead of mapping files.

Comment: ok then your configuration file needs single and you need to be using propertyplaceholder for property file configuration.you will have to externalize the 4 different db connection parameters to a property file. not sure why u want to load 4 tables for 4 different db in a single program. that sounds like a bad database design. please try to change it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one hibernate xml file for specifying the databases and 4 hbm files separately for mapping each table with the class.